Get static IP of server which nginx is running on in C
I have a nginx reverse proxy server listening on 0.0.0.0 with server_name feng.cc:8080, the partial config is as follows:
upstream ssl-proxy {
    server 172.16.43.210:5000;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name feng.cc:8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://ssl-proxy/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host  $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}

The static IP of the nginx server is 172.16.39.52, and feng.cc is a customed domain name maps to the static IP in hosts file.
I have nginx modules writen in C, but I don't know how to get the static IP in the modules.
I found there are some data members in the ngx_http_request_s structure, e.g. r->connection->local_sockaddr, and r->connection->listening,
but these give me 0.0.0.0 instead of the static IP.
I also found that the nginx server communicated with the upstream server via static IP:
$ hostname -I
172.16.39.52

$ tcpdump -nn -iany dst port 5000
eth0  Out IP 172.16.39.52.26130 > 172.16.43.210.5000: Flags [S], seq 3565149610, win 32120, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1811543954 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
eth0  Out IP 172.16.39.52.26130 > 172.16.43.210.5000: Flags [.], ack 515140155, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 1811543955 ecr 2228136305], length 0
eth0  Out IP 172.16.39.52.26130 > 172.16.43.210.5000: Flags [P.], seq 0:139, ack 1, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 1811543955 ecr 2228136305], length 139
eth0  Out IP 172.16.39.52.26130 > 172.16.43.210.5000: Flags [.], ack 174, win 250, options [nop,nop,TS val 1811543957 ecr 2228136307], length 0
eth0  Out IP 172.16.39.52.26130 > 172.16.43.210.5000: Flags [.], ack 203, win 250, options [nop,nop,TS val 1811543957 ecr 2228136307], length 0
eth0  Out IP 172.16.39.52.26130 > 172.16.43.210.5000: Flags [F.], seq 139, ack 203, win 250, options [nop,nop,TS val 1811543958 ecr 2228136307], length 0
eth0  Out IP 172.16.39.52.26130 > 172.16.43.210.5000: Flags [.], ack 204, win 250, options [nop,nop,TS val 1811543959 ecr 2228136309], length 0

Is there any way to get the static IP of nginx server in C programming?

Sadly, I received two downvotes, maybe my description is unclear or the question itself is not suitable in here.
Anyway, I finally found the solution that is using socket fd to get the nginx server IPv4 address:
char server_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

// worked
struct sockaddr_in laddr;
socklen_t laddr_len = sizeof(laddr);
if (getsockname(r->connection->fd, (struct sockaddr*)&laddr, &laddr_len) == 0) {
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &laddr.sin_addr, server_ip, sizeof(server_ip));
}

Insead of directly using r->connection->local_sockaddr:
char server_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

// doesn't work
struct sockaddr_in* laddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)(r->connection->local_sockaddr);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &r->connection->local_sockaddr, server_ip, sizeof(server_ip));

